# MessageDialog Access Denied Exception

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps

I'm getting access denied error message when try to show two message dialogs at the same time.

Case: I'm calling two async service call's and showing service error message response to MessageDialog.

In above case, If I don't have internet connection two message dialog throwing same time and getting "Access Denied" error message.

I'm using below code for showing error message:

```
MessageDialog dialog = new MessageDialog(responseBase.error.Description, responseBase.error.Title);
await dialog.ShowAsync();
```

Comment: dup of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12722490/messagedialog-showasync-throws-accessdenied-exception-on-second-dialog

Comment: @xyroid - why not vote to close as duplicate?

Comment: I am having problem while closing. Every time I get [this](http://img31.imageshack.us/img31/6412/m7s.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[WinRT - MessageDialog.ShowAsync will throw UnauthorizedAccessException in my custom class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13813065/winrt-messagedialog-showasync-will-throw-unauthorizedaccessexception-in-my-cus)

Please refer to above link... In your case, this will work.

Thanks,